# How to play a sound from RAW folder before assets?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a scenario where user turn on details by clicking a button in settings page and when details are on, it will play a details audio of 10 seconds before an audio on page2 that is implemented below in code and if user turn off details by clicking again a button in settings page it will directly plays an audio that is implemented below.

this is settings page where is used sharedprefrences

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            SavePreferencesInteger("audio",0,getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Qari 1 Voice selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            SavePreferencesInteger("audio",1,getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Qari 2 Voice is not available ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}


public static void SavePreferencesInteger(String key, int value,Context context){

    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("NooraniQaida",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
public static int GetPreferencesInteger(String key,Context context){

    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("NooraniQaida",0);
    int savedPreferences = pref.getInt(key, 0);
    return savedPreferences;
}

public static void saveStringSet(Context context,String value, HashSet<String> mSet) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(value, mSet);
    editor.apply();
}
```

this is my button on page2

```
case R.id.pg2_4: {

            clearcolor();
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                clearcolor();
            }
            try {
                pg2_4.setColorFilter(0xff00ff00, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
                mp.reset();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
                if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 0) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p2_1.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 1) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p3_1.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 2) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q3p2_1.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 3) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q4p2_1.mp3");
                }
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    clearcolor();
                }
            });
            break ;
        }
```

anyone help me to make this possible and page2 is a fragment.

Comment: What does `... from RAW folder before assets ...` mean?

Comment: @KlingKlang sir i just want to play an audio before if details button is on

Comment: You need to retrieve the audio file from the app space or the storage (i.e.: from `assets`) and play it by using your favorite method (SoundPool, MediaPlayer, ...).

Comment: @KlingKlang sir sound is playing but i need to play another audiio before the actual audio if details button is on and if its off it plays only actual audio.

Comment: So, play 2 files one after the other. One is only played on a condition and the other one is played anyway. I still don't get which is the problematic point.

Comment: @KlingKlang how can i play 2 audio on one click through assets. 1 on condition and 1 will always

Comment: @KlingKlang can you guide me from my code above as regular audio is playing but condition audio im not getting it

Comment: There must be some issue in how you set and retrieve the preferences. And/or some logical error (i.e.: it's not clear where do you start the MediaPlayer for the second sound). Also, you could avoid executing the same instruction in all your if conditions by simply reading the setting once in a variable.

Comment: @KlingKlang i did not yet implemented to play second audio guide me plz how to do it

Comment: Well... just the same way you play ONE sound, you can play the OTHER one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 player = MediaPlayer.create(MyService.this, R.raw.your_file_name);
 player.start();
```

Hope this helps you.